Disabled SQL Server job still being run
SQL Server 15.0.4395.2
We have a SSIS package that we run to interface with another system. It is (or was) run from a SQL Server Agent job, and scheduled to run every hour.
For reasons outside the scope of this question, the link to the other system became defunct and the package fails whenever it is run. This is not a problem - we disabled the job in SQL Server Agent, and according to the Job Activity Monitor (both the main screen and the job history screen) it hasn't run since 8th August. That's absolutely what we expect to see.
But if we go to the database in Integration Service Catalogs and run the All Executions report, that package still shows up as being run (and failing) every hour. There's nothing running with that frequency in SQL Server Agent, where is that job coming from? Is there some other way of scheduling packages to run that won't show up in SQL Agent? It's a fairly old system, so there might be ancient code lurking somewhere!

Could the SSIS package have been coded with retry logic and it's just been repeatedly retrying ever since it was last ran from the SQL Agent Job? Try to see if it's the same instance in the All Executions report (maybe by some sort of ID)?


Is there some other way of scheduling packages to run that won't show up in SQL Agent?

The package can be fired without Job by catalog.create_execution
Here are examples how else it could be fired.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16
